# Why current branch is not moved while rebasing?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am currently on `dev` branch and have some changes on `local/dev` branch.

[image]
...
[image]

I did rebase:

```sh
$ git rebase dev local/dev
Created autostash: 92915886
Applied autostash.
Successfully rebased and updated detached HEAD.
```

Commits are rebased but `dev` pointer is not updated:

[image]

Reading `man git rebase`:

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in <upstream>
> are saved to a temporary area

**This is the commits marked as `>` on second picture

> The current branch is reset to <upstream> ...

** `upstream` is `dev`. So I am on `dev` at this point

> The commits are then reapplied to the current branch

** Commits are reapplied to `dev`

**Why `dev` pointer is not moved to top with `HEAD`?**

Should I apply some option to move my current `dev` on top with `HEAD`?

**UPDATE**
This is very very strage. When `dev` and `local/dev` differ liner and could be fas forwarded, then my `dev` is moved on top as I am expected to work. Without any extra

```
git branch -f dev
git checkout dev
```

How history looks before rebase:
[image]
and how after rebase:
[image]

Comment: "reset to upstream" doesn't mean "checks out upstream". The branch you're rebasing is made to point to the same commit that upstream branch points to. You will only affect the branch you're rebasing, not the one you're rebasing on top of.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: 1. Ok, it does not checkout to `dev`. So there is no current branch. What does man means when saying: `then reapplied to the current branch`? 2. `You will only affect the branch you're rebasing`. I am rebasing commits at `local/dev` on top of upstream. The branch `local/dev` after rebasing is left intact. What do you mean it will be affected? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why `dev` pointer is not moved to top with `HEAD`?* -- because it is **not** the current branch during the rebase.

Read the [documentation of `git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) carefully. It explains in the first paragraph:

> ```
> git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec <cmd>]
>         [--onto <newbase> | --keep-base] [<upstream> [<branch>]]`
> ```
>
> If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git switch <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

In plain English, if `git rebase` is invoked with two branches (`<upstream>` and `<branch>`), it first switches to the second branch then rebase it on top of the first branch.<sup>*</sup>

This means that:

```
git rebase dev local/dev
```

is a shortcut for:

```
git switch local/dev
git rebase dev
```

The current branch during the rebase is `local/dev`; it is the only branch that is affected by the rebase.

---

<sup>*</sup> `<upstream>` does not need to be a branch. Any reference that identifies a commit (branch, tag, commit, `HEAD`, `HEAD^2`, `HEAD@{1}` etc) can be used as `<upstream>`.

`<branch>`, on the other hand, needs to be a branch because, as a result of the rebase, it will move to a different commit.

---

### Update

You interpret the documentation incorrectly. You say in the question:

> The current branch is reset to `<upstream>` ...
>
> > ** upstream is dev. So I am on dev at this point

The current branch on that point is not necessarily `dev` (it is, in fact, `local/dev` as explained above).

*"The current branch is reset to `<upstream>`"* does not mean that `<upstream>` becomes the current branch but that the current branch (`local/dev`) is moved to the commit identified by `<upstream>`. What Git does at this point is equivalent to `git reset --hard <upstream>`.

---

### Update #2

The analysis above ignores the fact that `local/dev` is a remote branch. I didn't notice that initially.
*What's the point of naming a remote `local`? It is misleading.*

Because `local/dev` is not a local branch, `git switch local/dev` brings the repo in a [detached `HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) state. The rest of the rebase happens as described in the documentation but in the end you have a new history line and no branch that points to it (except for `HEAD`). If you switch the branch the result of the rebase is lost.

There are two ways to fix the things:

- Move the branch `dev` on the current commit. There are several ways to do this but the easiest way is to use `git branch -f dev`.
- Abandon the changes, switch to the `dev` branch and do the rebase correctly:

  ```
  git switch dev
  git rebase local/dev
  ```

#### The real solution

All in all, the entire situation appeared because you put the branches in the incorrect order in the command line. It should be:

```
git rebase local/dev dev
```

This checks out the `dev` branch then moves the commits accessible from `dev` and not accessible from `local/dev` on top of `local/dev` while it preserves the `dev` branch on top of the moved commits. On a quick glance it looks like the branch `dev` is cut from where it forks from branch `local/dev` and the piece is then grafted on top of `local/dev`.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Now I understand what is coming on. Thank you

Comment: I update the question. There is the case when my `git rebase dev local/dev` moves `dev` branch to top

Comment: `local` is the name that was set on a `remote`. It's not something that is somehow set by git. It was used when a remote was added to that repo that you are working on and who is git to refuse if the developer wants to add a remote repo naming it as `local` on said repo? So, somebody ran this on that repo, back in time: `git remote add local https://blahblah/url/to/repo`. Not the best pick for naming a remote, certainly.

Answer (score 2):

`local/dev` is a remote branch. It won't move just because you want to rebase it. It will be done in `detached HEAD` and then it's up to you to push into `local/dev`

```
git push local -f HEAD:dev
```

Also you can move `dev` to `HEAD` and then checkout it:

```
git branch -f dev
git checkout dev
```

Comment: I do not want to change `local/dev`. I am speaking about `dev`

Comment: Even more so... you _didn't_ ask to rebase `dev`, what you ran there is asking to rebase `local/dev` **on top of** `dev`.  If you want to set dev where you are after the operation is done then you need to run `git branch -f dev`. And then you might consider checking it out.

Comment: Voteup, but removed accepted answer, because there is no answer how to did that automatically

Comment: I updated the question. Here is the case when my `git rebase` work without this extra commands

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move `dev` to get the revisions that were applied on `local/dev`, you can do this:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick $( git merge-base HEAD local/dev )..local/dev
```

That should do

Answer (score -1):

I do not find an option to move `dev` branch to `HEAD` automatically.

But after rebasing I can check out back to `dev` and the fastforward to `c1692f`:

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge --ff-only c1692f
```

Here is result:
[image]

Comment: Or `git branch -f dev; git checkout dev`. No need to move from where you are.

Comment: @eftshift0: Same thing I have added to you answer a few moments ago :D

Comment: Yep, noticed. Thaks